# Turning off clover coverage - not working

Tags: java, maven, clover

I know that I am gonna have to use `// CLOVER: OFF` to turn off clover test coverage. I have read https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/CLOVER/Using+Source+Directives

I have added that line before my class declaration like:

`// CLOVER: OFF
public class SampleClass{
    /*
     * Some definitions
     */
}`

This thing worked for me yesterday and failing today. I am scratching my head trying to figure out a reason for failure.

But, my maven build failed because it did not meet the coverage percentage. I am using maven 3.3.9 and eclipse Neon for my project.

Answer (score 2):

It's the space between *CLOVER:* and *OFF* which causes problems. You should use the directives exactly as it's described in the docs

```
// CLOVER:ON
// CLOVER:OFF
```

Are you trying to exclude whole file from instrumentation? If so you can simply exclude classes from instrumentation on a Maven or Eclipse level. Documentation links:

- https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/CLOVER/Configuring+instrumentation
- https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/CLOVER/4.+Scope+of+instrumentation+in+Eclipse#id-4.ScopeofinstrumentationinEclipse-Excludingandincludingpackages

Comment: I did that, still did not work. The exact same string worked for me earlier.

Comment: correct me if I am wrong. But, I think that this is caused because of not having doc strings placed correctly

Answer (score 1):

If you want to exclude one complete class from clover, you can do this in the pom configuration.

```
<configuration>
  <excludes>
    <exclude>**/SampleClass.java</exclude>
  </excludes>
</configuration>
```

If you want to exclude just one or more methods, use CLOVER:OFF/CLOVER:ON around them.

```
public class SampleClass {
    private int num;

    public SampleClass() {
        // intentionally left blank
    }

    // CLOVER:OFF
    public void setNum(int num) {
        this.num = num;
    }
    // CLOVER:ON
}
```

Beware of the fact that clover will still scan the excluded code if you have nothing left to scan in the class, hence the empty constructor.

Comment: Hi, for me adding  // CLOVER:OFF // CLOVER:ON does not work. What could be the possible cause for this? Do I need to add anything on my buid.gradle file for this purpose ?